# How to allow OpportunityLineItem delete but not Opportunity delete

Tags: opportunity, permissions, profile, permission-sets, opportunity-lineitem

How can I stop users from deleting `Opportunity`'s but allow them to delete `OpportunityLineItem`s?

Because `OpportunityLineItem` is a child record of `Opportunity` it is not possible to control it's object settings via a `Profile` or `Persmission Set`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Grant the users Edit but not Delete on Opportunity via Profile or Permission Set. They will be able to delete Opportunity Products (aka `OpportunityLineItem`) on any Opportunities to which they have Read/Write sharing access.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `before delete` trigger on `Opportunity` which will prevent deletion of records for all users or certain profiles. Quick example:

```
trigger OpportunitiesTrigger on Opportunity (before delete) {
    if (Trigger.isBefore && Trigger.isDelete) {
        for (Opportunity opp : Trigger.old) {
            opp.addError('You cannot delete Opportunity records');
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest simply deleting it in a trigger based on a 'deleteMe' checkbox on the OpportunityLineItem.  The check box can be set using a quick action, and need not be on the page layout.  The trigger runs in 'system mode' and will perform the delete regardless of user permission on the Opportunity.

```
trigger DeleteOli on OpportunityLineItem(after insert, after update) 
{
    List<OpportunityLineItem> olisToDelete = new List<OpportunityLineItem>();

    // get the opportunity line items marked for deletion... 
    for(OpportunityLineItem oli: Trigger.new)
        if (oli.deleteMe__c)
            olisToDelete.add(oli);

    //  we now have a list of opportunity line items we want to delete
    if(!olisToDelete.isEmpty())
        delete olisToDelete;
}
```